# Illegal else without matching if

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error message that says illegal else without matching if. I think something is wrong with my else statement, but I don't see where. Do I have an unneeded bracket? It's on line 78 column 2. Thank you

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

string service_code,            //hold the service code 
       account_number;          //hold the account number
double final_amount = 0,        // hold the final amount
       final_damount,           //hold the amount for the day minutes
       minutes = 0,             //hold the amount for minutes
       day_minutes = 0,         // hold the amount for fay minutes
       night_minutes = 0,      //hold the amount for night minutes
       final_namount = 0;        //hold the amount for night minutes


cout << "Please enter your account number: "; 
cin >> account_number;      //Entering the account number                       
cout << "Please enter your service code (r or R for regular service and p or P for premium service): "; 
cin >> service_code;        //Enteringthe service code
cout << "Please enter the amount of minutes used: ";
cin >> minutes;             //Entering the minutes you used
if(service_code == "r" || "R")
{

if(minutes <= 50)

    final_amount = 10;
    cout << "Your final amount is $: " << final_amount << endl;         //Displaying final amount when your minutes are less than or equal to 50
}
    {
    if(minutes > 50)

    final_amount = (minutes - 50) * 0.20 + 10;
    cout << "Your final amount is: $ " << final_amount << endl;         //Displaying final amount when your minutes are greater than 50
}
    {
     else if(service_code == "p" || "P")

        cout << "Please enter the amount of minutes used during the day: " << day_minutes << endl;              //Entering minutes used during the day
        cout << "Please enter the amount of minutes used during the night: " << night_minutes << endl;          //Entering minutes used during the night
    }
        {
if(day_minutes <=75)

    final_damount = 0;
    final_amount = final_damount + final_namount + 20;              //Calculating final amount for minutes used during the day
        }
        {
 if(day_minutes > 75)
    final_damount = day_minutes * 0.10;
    final_amount = final_damount + final_namount + 20;              //Calcuating final amount for minutes used during the day
}
    {
if(night_minutes <= 100)

    final_namount = 0;
    final_amount = final_damount + final_namount + 20;              //Calcuating final amount for minutes used during the night
    }
{
if(night_minutes > 100)

    final_namount = night_minutes * 0.05;
    final_amount = final_damount + final_namount + 20;              //Calcuating final amount for minutes used during the night
    cout << "Your final amount is: $ " << final_amount << endl;     //Displaying final amount
}
{
else

    cout << "Error, this program does not accept negative numbers.\n";      //Displaying error message
    cout << "Account number: " << account_number << endl;           //Displaying account number
    cout << "Service code: " << service_code << endl;               //Displaying service code
    cout << "Service code: " << minutes << endl;                    //Displaying minutes
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're missing opening braces on several of your `if` statements

Comment: Missing lots of `{ }`.  It is a good habit to use curly brackets for `if` statements, even if the block is only a single line.  Especially useful in situations like this.

Comment: First try indenting your code properly, then you will see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: A common problem for Python-converted C(++) programmers, as witnessed by the indentation.

Comment: Curly Braces for single statement blocks are an annoyance. Still, some like them. Some even always explicitly test for != 0. Anyway, sometimes running indent with your preferred options over your sources (or using a good editor) is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Most of your `if` statements are missing their opening curly-braces. This means that the completely wrong code is actually being executed by your program because only the first statement after each `if` statement will be executed if the conditional expression is true and the rest of the code will always be executed.

...this is the same issue as Apple's infamous `goto error` bug: http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/

C is not Python, indentation is not respected by the compiler and it does not mean code belongs to a certain keyword or block.

I strongly suggest reading up on C's syntax, and it's (generally) a good idea to always use curly-braces with all statement blocks (`if`, `for`, `do`, `while`, etc) to help avoid nasties like these. Internally, my team at Microsoft, runs a program called StyleCop which won't let us check-in code to our central repository if it contains any brace-less statements.

Comment: Do you also force-run a code-reformatter?

Comment: @Deduplicator My team doesn't, instead StyleCop ensures that our code meets the style, formatting, and indentation guidelines so that automatic-reformatting is not necessary.